# Copy sheet to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have a subroutine in a module with this code:

```
Set wkbGraph_Generator = ActiveWorkbook
```

In a different module I have this global variable.

```
Public wkbCompiledDataTable As New Collection
```

In a different module I have a subroutine that has this:

```
wkbCompiledDataTable.Add Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilePath, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

The function where I am having trouble:

```vb
Function RTFN_GetDataActual(wkbCompiledDataTable As Collection, _
                            wkbGraph_Generator As Workbook)

    wkbCompiledDataTable(1).Sheets(1).Copy After:=wkbGraph_Generator.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    wkbGraph_Generator.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = TagArray(1)

End Function
```

I get

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

If I step through sometimes it works. I think it's in the "Sheets.Count" because sometimes the sheets.count = 3 which isn't right. Other times the sheets.count is correct.

I think the focus is on the wrong worksheet when it does sheets.count.

The code just had an error on that line then I clicked on the "wkbGraph_Generator" effectively activating it and the code worked.

Comment: `Sheets.Count` refers to the count in the activeworkbook. If you want it to be that specific workbook, you need to be *explicit* about that.

Comment: A `With` statement, as posted in my answer, is an efficient way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sheets.Count` has an implicit `ActiveWorkbook`. Be *explicit* - specify the workbook. A `With` statement is a good way to do this. Note the `.` before all instances of `Sheets`, including in `.Sheets.Count`:

```
Function RTFN_GetDataActual(wkbCompiledDataTable As Collection, _
                        wkbGraph_Generator As Workbook)

    With wkbGraph_Generator
        wkbCompiledDataTable(1).Sheets(1).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = TagArray(1)
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... struggled with this last night... basically figured out my own answer while posting the question.

Change:

```
wkbCompiledDataTable(1).Sheets(1).Copy After:=wkbGraph_Generator.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

To:

```
wkbCompiledDataTable(1).Sheets(1).Copy After:=wkbGraph_Generator.Sheets(wkbGraph_Generator.Sheets.Count)
```

PS: everywhere online shows simply "Sheets.Count" for copying a worksheet from one workbook to another... Based on what i found... it doesn't seem like that would ever work.